# Приложение на asp.net mvc + angular 7

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, angular

Начинаю изучать angular. Скачал node.js установил angular 7.2.12, angular cli 7.3.8.
По примеру попробовал сделать первый проект. Но почему то не заработало.
Вот как сейчас выглядит мой проект:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот мой код.

app.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'MyAngular';
}
```

app.component.html:

```
<!--The content below is only a placeholder and can be replaced.-->
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h1>
    Welcome to {{ title }}!
  </h1>
  <img width="300" alt="Angular Logo" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAyNTAgMjUwIj4KICAgIDxwYXRoIGZpbGw9IiNERDAwMzEiIGQ9Ik0xMjUgMzBMMzEuOSA2My4ybDE0LjIgMTIzLjFMMTI1IDIzMGw3OC45LTQzLjcgMTQuMi0xMjMuMXoiIC8+CiAgICA8cGF0aCBmaWxsPSIjQzMwMDJGIiBkPSJNMTI1IDMwdjIyLjItLjFWMjMwbDc4LjktNDMuNyAxNC4yLTEyMy4xTDEyNSAzMHoiIC8+CiAgICA8cGF0aCAgZmlsbD0iI0ZGRkZGRiIgZD0iTTEyNSA1Mi4xTDY2LjggMTgyLjZoMjEuN2wxMS43LTI5LjJoNDkuNGwxMS43IDI5LjJIMTgzTDEyNSA1Mi4xem0xNyA4My4zaC0zNGwxNy00MC45IDE3IDQwLjl6IiAvPgogIDwvc3ZnPg==">
</div>
<h2>Here are some links to help you start: </h2>
<ul>
  <li>
    <h2><a target="_blank" rel="noopener" href="https://angular.io/tutorial">Tour of Heroes</a></h2>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h2><a target="_blank" rel="noopener" href="https://angular.io/cli">CLI Documentation</a></h2>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h2><a target="_blank" rel="noopener" href="https://blog.angular.io/">Angular blog</a></h2>
  </li>
</ul>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Index.cshtml:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Angular Page";
}

@section Scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/libs/runtime.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/libs/polyfills.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/libs/styles.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/libs/vendor.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/libs/main.js"></script>
}

<app-root>Загрузка...</app-root>
```

Но почему то не выводиться страничка с помощью angular. Выводиться только то что на индексе. Может я какие то связи не указал что бы всё подтягивалось с помощью тега `

Подскажите пожалуйста, что у меня не так? Если понадобиться ещё какой то код, пишите, прикреплю.

RouteConfig:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

Скрин запущенного приложения:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ошибка на клиенте после запуска:

> main.ts:12 Error: No base href set. Please provide a value for the APP_BASE_HREF token or add a base element to the document.

Код main.ts:

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

UPDATE:

Новый вариант компонента:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    template: `<h1>Добро пожаловать {{name}}!</h1>
                <label>Введите имя:</label>
                <input [(ngModel)]="name" placeholder="name">`
})
export class AppComponent {
    name = 'Tom';
}
```

Comment: `По примеру` - какому примеру? В чем различие примкра и вашего кода? Пример запускали?  `не выводиться` - где? Какой УРЛ? Настройки роутнинга? Ошибки на странице? (пробовали F12 в браузере нажать и поглядеть ошибки?)

Comment: @tym32167 в качестве примера нашёл видео с youtube.

Comment: Пример route config привёл в вопросе. Сейчас ещё добавлю скрин того что запустилось.

Comment: у меня ютуб заблочен, но я же не один здесь - как считаете, имеет ли смысл добавить ссылку на ресурс, по которому вы делали свой пример, в вопрос?

Comment: @tym32167 у меня тоже на работе заблокирован. Добавить ссылку не смогу, если только после работы. Дополнил вопрос ошибкой с клиента. И небольшими дополнениями.

Comment: Пробовали гуглить эту ошибку? Я не фронтенд совсем, но, мне кажется, вы не указали базовый адрес для генератора урлов

Comment: @tym32167 сейчас вот это гуглю. Я видел пример для route config. Вместо `url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",` написать `url: "{*url}",`, но это не помогло.

Comment: не трогайте серверный роутинг, я вам про роутинг агнуляра говорю (у вас 2 роутинга, один на сервере, второй на клиенте)

Comment: @tym32167 добавил в _Layout.cshtml строчку `<base href="" />` всё заработало. Но должен наверное быть какой то более изящный способ роутинга? Ну наверное раз вы не фронтенд, вопрос не по адресу. Может кто то подскажет более валидный вариант.

Comment: вам @tym32167 все правильно сказал, не трогайте серверный роутинг. И какой более изящный способ? наверное не стоит смешивать .net + angular, в продакшене webpack гененирует хеши для js файлов, а также за вас билдит `index.html`, который должен использоваться вместо `index.cshtml`

Comment: @overthesanity ну значит так и нужно настраивать роут? С помощью `<base href="" />` ?. Просто если так, то я сейчас попробовал изменить app.component на пример с metanit. И теперь он не ссылается на app.component.html, но всё равно выводит её. В вопросе пример нового компонента привожу.

Comment: в моем старом домашнем проекте это выглядело так  https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2Atc.png , но я писал фронт отдельно, бек - отдельно

Comment: @overthesanity я сейчас даже попробовал удалить код из `app.component,ts` и всё равно выводиться то что и выводилось. Получается эта стрчока `<base href="" />` в _Layout независимо от компонентов просто выводит app.component.html. Как всё таки правильно настроить роутинг что бы я мог выводить свои компоненты?